# To select region of the image

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB 2015a. I want to select the particular object from an image with the help of mouse so that it can make square around the object and I want to return the pixels of selected object. How should I do that? Help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

[`getrect`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/getrect.html?refresh=true) function does the trick.

**From the documentation:**

> `rect = getrect` lets you select a rectangle in the current axes using
>   the mouse. Use the mouse to click and drag the desired rectangle. rect
>   is a four-element vector with the form `[xmin ymin width height]`. To
>   constrain the rectangle to be a square, use a shift- or right-click to
>   begin the drag.

**Example for an image:**

You can use these coordinates/ dimensions as indices for your image matrix.

```
Im = imshow('moon.tif');

rect = getrect;
xmin = round( rect(1) )
ymin = round( rect(2) )
width = round( rect(3) )
height = round( rect(4) )

xvec = xmin:xmin+width;
yvec = ymin:ymin+height;
imshow( Im.CData( yvec, xvec ) );
```

**Example for a function plot:**

```
t = 0:0.1:10;
y = sin(t);
plot( t, y );
```

Then call `getrect`:

[image]

It returns the rectangle coordinates/ dimensions:

```
ans =

    2.4309   -0.4665    4.5161    0.7230
```

Comment: now i want to use these pixel values to convert it into real world dimensions of selected object i.e. mm, cm, m etc. How should i do that ?